# No ParameterResolver registered for an @RepeatedTest

Tags: junit5

I have a **not** parameterized but `@RepeatedTest`. When running the acceptance test, the failsafe plugin throws `ParameterResolutionException` (no `ParameterResolver` registered for parameter) for `@BeforeEach` method (in the testcase parent class) which accepts `RepetitionInfo`. The pom.xml has for JUnit:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As I've understood from the documentation (§3.11, §3.13.1), nothing else is required (`RepetitionInfoParameterResolver` is registered automatically and `RepetitionInfo` is available `@BeforeEach`), but it seems I'm wrong. What should I do?

... and now the code :-)

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
@Target(METHOD)
@RepeatedTest(AcceptanceTestUtil.MAX_WEBBROWSER_COUNT)
@Tag("AcceptanceTest")
@Test // <- bug lies here, conflicts with @RepeatedTest
public @interface AcceptanceTest {

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code please (or at least a [mcve] of it)? It's quite possible that you understood the documentation correctly but made a mistake in the implementation.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a `@Test` method in the same class as the `@RepeatedTest` method which would cause such a failure, but if you don't show us your code... this is only speculation.

Comment: Sam, you've got it, thank you. Somehow I've missed to remove that after making the test repeated and didn't noticed this even after several reviews. Please make your comment an answer to let me accept it.